# Passing an Java array from Spring MVC controller to a JSP script var variable throwing error

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

**Back Story:** I'm creating a webpage that displays the daily access count to a server over an entire month in bar graph format.

**Libraries/Technologies:**

- Spring Boot - for the MVC back end
- .JSP - for the actual webpage layout
- D3 Javascript - for the creating of the graphical elements
- Tomcat - for the running of the whole mess

So I've collected the data in an interger array in the page controller and are passing it to a variable in the JSP page script section. The problem I'm having is that .JSP throws a *"Illegal Character"* error if I pass it as an int array or *"Missing ] after element list"* error if I pass it as a string array.

The specific errors don't matter to me at this point. I'm just looking how to pass the data (preferably as an int array) into the script variable so i can pass it to the D3 code for graphing.

Here is how the data is passed from controller code to the .JSP page

```
//converting from list to array and translating to string if int array is impossible
        index = 0;
        String[] graph1Data = new String[dailyCount.size()];
        for(int i : dailyCount) {
            graph1Data[index] = dailyCount.get(index).toString();
            log.info(index + " = " + graph1Data[index]);
            index++;
        }

//passing data to the JSP page
        mav.addObject("serverName", serverInstance.getName());
        mav.addObject("month",month);
        mav.addObject("hostItems", hostItems);
        mav.addObject("totals", totalItems);
        mav.addObject("graph1Data", graph1Data);


        return mav;
```

this is the code where I take the passed data and try to assign it to the script variable

```
//java script code above

        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

        var src = ${graph1Data}); //<<-- attempting to assign to script variable

        var msvg = d3.select("#mGraph"), 
            margin = 100, 
            width = msvg.attr("width") - margin,
            height = msvg.attr("height") - margin;

        var data = [10, 50, 15, 30, 20]; //<<-- what the passed data will replace 

//more D3 graphing code below
```

this is what is actually ends up in the variable causing the errors

- int array - `var src = [I@be6d99b);`
- string array - `var src = [Ljava.lang.String;@d0baa7f);`

any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: This is a case where Thymeleaf (which understands JS scripting and can do inlining like this cleanly) is substantially friendlier to work with than JSP.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- wish i could switch, but this is a work project, so i don't have much choice in the matter

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to pass lists instead of arrays from controllers? In that case list of integers toString() method would produce string having same syntax as javascript array.

For list of strings it would be necessary to add quotation marks for each string to achieve same syntax as in javascript. E.g.:

```
    String[] graph1Data = new String[dailyCount.size()];
    for(int i : dailyCount) {
        // adding quotation marks
        graph1Data[index] = "'" + dailyCount.get(index).toString() + "'";
        log.info(index + " = " + graph1Data[index]);
        index++;
    }
    // convert array to list when adding it to model-and-view
    mav.addObject("graph1Data", Arrays.asList(graph1Data));
```